# Some space between elements without any reason I can figure out

Tags: html, css

```
<div id="colorscheme">
</div>
<div id="content">
<div id="display_saved">
 TEXT TEXT TEXT   
</div>
```

This is HTML structure of related to issue document.

CSS:

```
#colorscheme{
    width:25%;
    display:inline-block;
    height: 50px;
    background:green;
}
#content{
    width:50%;
    display:inline-block;
    background: gray;
     box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    
}
#display_saved{
    border: solid 1px red;
    padding: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    width:100%;

}
```

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4mpbs/)

As you can see from the feedle, there is some space between #colorscheme and #content, despite there is no margins, and there is border-box property. How can I reduce it?

Comment: just add float left property to #colorscheme,#content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just whitespace, which is logical because you've reduced your blocklevel elements to inline blocks explicitly. Eliminate the whitespace and it'll go away:

```
<div id="colorscheme"></div><div id="content"><div id="display_saved">TEXT TEXT TEXT </div></div>
```

Comment: To be more specific it's the whitespace between the 2 divs giving the issue so if you close colorscheme and then open content without any whitespace (including line-break) betweebn then it should be fixed, like: `</div><div id="content">`

Comment: This isn't what I would suggest as being the 'correct' solution. Code should be well formatted and readable and removing white space negates this!

Comment: That's open for discussion @Chris - applying an `inline` property to `display` means that it will then follow all rules for inline content - being that all consecutive whitespace is collapsed into a single space, meaning a gap between the blocks depending on your HTML markup. As long as there's no `white-space:strip` property in CSS that means either fixing the HTML or using another 'hack'. This is less hacky than the popular `font-size:0` hack on the parent.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes Certainly is up for discussion and I think you are right in what you say. It is in many ways down to the developer as to the best solution as there is more than one perfectly viable solution.

Answer (score 4):

Inline block can cause whitespace issues and I would recommend floating the elements.

Have a look at this forked example - http://jsfiddle.net/DkhDm/1/

It's also worth noting that display inline-block lacks support in some browsers - which is another reason to always use floats ahead of it! You do however have the small added complication of clearing the floats but this is easily achieved.

```
#colorscheme{
    width:25%;
    float: left;
    height: 50px;
    background:green;
}
#content{
    width:50%;
    float: left;
    background: gray;
     box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    
}
#display_saved{
    border: solid 1px red;
    padding: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    width:100%; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4mpbs/1/)

CSS:

```
#colorscheme{
    width:25%;
    display:block;
    height: 50px;
    background:green;
    float:left;
}
```

i have added `float:left;` and changed to `display:block;`

Answer (score 0):

You can move the elements back into place with negative 4px of margin. (Not in IE6,7). inline-block do cause whitespace, i don't think it's a bug and it's rather nice to have when using inline-block on text-elements.

```
#colorscheme{
    margin-right: -4px;
    width:25%;
    display:inline-block;
    height: 50px;
    background:green;
}
```

Comment: This 'solution' depends on rounding of legacy and future browsers to always render a space as 4 pixels, regardless of font, platform and DPI settings. I wouldn't rely on this.

Comment: bad idea, different output in different browsers

Answer (score 0):

You can also use html comments to eliminate the whitespace.

```
<div>
  <p>Content</p>
</div><!--
--><div>
  <p>More content</p>
</div>
```